I need to reduce the double click delay
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and tried through settings but I need to reduce this value even more. Please help with my question.

Setting> Accessability > Double click delay > ... move the slider to the far left end (short); at this setting I cannot double click, whatever I try. One Cursor up or right and I have about 50% success... a second cursor right and that rises to 80-90% - do you have some other experience?
